# how to change the redirect-time in phpmyadmin 5.1.0 after editing tables

Tags: phpmyadmin

after altering an sql table in phpmyadmin 5.1.0, the changing Code is shown for a second before redirectiung to the default table view.

Can i change this "redirect-time"?

It´s pretty short for copying the SQL Code, which i need to store for documentation.

Thx in advance

summsel